# C++ Deep Copy of a structure that embeds many simple variables plus one nested structure ..(memcpy?)

Tags: c++, nested, structure, memcpy, deep-copy

I have

```
struct  Parent
{
    int child1;
    int child2;
     char child3;
     float child 4;
     anotherStruct child5;
};

typedef struct
{
    unsigned char  x;
    int            y;
    char           z;
    float          a;
    int            b;
    char           c;
    etc ..
  } anotherStruct;

Parent   myFirstParent;
Parent   mySecondParent;

///I want to do a deep copy of myFirstParent into mySecondParent. 
//does the follwowing work for that purpose??
memcpy (&mySecondParent, &myFirstParent, sizeof(myFirstParent);
```

I am investigating the answer myself but meanwhile I am posting the question because of extreme time constraint.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: "_...because of extreme time constraint_" How is that relevant?

Answer (score 5):

In your case, assignment should work just fine:

```
mySecondParent = myFirstParent;
```

After all, none of the  structs define pointers.

Also, if there were pointers, even `memcpy` would not work, as it doesn't do deep-copy. In that case, you had to manually copy the *content* of the pointers.

By the way, your code wouldn't compile, as you're using `anotherStruct` *before* defining it. Please define `anotherStruct` before `Parent`.

Comment: If **Parent** struct had a std::map or std::string as one of its member, will mySecondParent = myFirstParent still work?

Comment: @Shyam: Yes. All standard containers/types support value-semantics, which means "assignment" does "deep-copy" the object.

Answer (score 2):

As a rule of thumb

> Keep in mind one thing: memcpy() is evil! It's a C construct you should never use in C++. memcpy() operates on bits and bytes, not on objects. At worst, it fails to take into account what's actually being stored in the objects you're copying, leading to erroneous results, or even uglier code that takes the special cases into account. Never use memcpy() in C++ code. There are always better, more object-oriented ways to do the same thing.

This mayn't apply to your case as you aren't using the free store, but for times when you may use the free store.

[SOURCE](http://icu-project.org/docs/papers/cpp_report/the_anatomy_of_the_assignment_operator.html)

Answer (score 1):

As there are no pointers in your class then the default compiler generated versions of the copy constructor and assignemnt operator will work just fine (doing what you call a deep copy).

Technically it is a shallow copy. A deep copy is when your class contains pointers and you need to make copies of the pointers content.

This should work fine without memcpy (which should never be used to copy C++ objects)

```
Parent   p1;
Parent   p2(p1);   // Make a copy of p1 into p2.
Parent   p3;

p1 = p3; // Use assignment operator works fine.
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple assigment strcture will work fine for you.  In general, the cimpiler (like the Microsoft compiler, and likey GCC) will pick the most efficient method for copying memory.  For small or simple things, a series of register loads and saves are often the most well performing.   The compiler may choose memcpy() for some things.

Other answers indicate that memcpy() should never be used wiht C++ classes.  This is generaly correct, but it can be used in some cases if you know whatyou are doing.  But this is almost never ncessary.

On AMD and Intel x86/x64 processors, memcpy() is always generated (or uses) the 'rep movesd' instruction. For many, many years, all modern processors are optimized for thi sinstruction, having special micro-code or other internal optmitions to ensure well performing small and mediaum sized memory moves.

THe best thing to do is simply look at the generated assembly language code in your debugger.   If your structure assignment does not end up with a series of simple load/stores, or memcopy (rep movesd) then you you can code one using memcpy() yourself.   This will work fine since your classes and strctures are using "plain-old-data". As anohter answer says, if your structure includes pointers then you will need code to handle those as shallow or deep copies, or reference counted objects.

As always, for 'hot' code paths, the profiler and performance measurment are essential tools.